# knockout js push different values to the same observable array

Tags: knockout.js

I am just learning more about knockout js, i am having a problem that when i push a table row to a template and then update the text field it updates all the inputs to the same value

ViewModel:

```
function viewModel() {
    var root = this;
    root.loop = ko.observableArray([]);
    root.table = ko.observableArray([]);
    root.value = ko.observable('');
    root.push = function() {
        root.loop.push('');
    }      
};
```

Html:

```
<input type="button" data-bind="click: $root.push, value: 'New Row'">
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'table',foreach: loop }">
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/html" id="table">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: $root.value"></td>
        <td><input type="button" data-bind="click: $root.save, value: 'Save'"></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

and here is a working example
http://html5imageeditor.co.uk/kopush
if you click on new row and add content then you will see what i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that all input values are bound to one observable.
You should do something like this:

```
function viewModel() {
    var root = this;
    root.loop = ko.observableArray([]);
    root.table = ko.observableArray([]);
    root.push = function () {
        root.loop.push({text: ''});
    }
};
```

As you can see, each times you click on the new button it will create and push a new item: `{ text: '' }`. So, each item has its own text property.

You also need to changed the view:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: text"></input></td>
    <td><input type="button" data-bind="click: $root.save, value: 'Save'"></input></td>
</tr>
```

Notice the input binding which is no longer bind to the `$root.value`, but to text property of the current item.

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2a426/)

Answer (score 0):

That's because all your fields are bound to $root.value, and $root refers to the highest level of your view model, in this case it always refers to the instance of your viewmodel object. Try binding to $data inside your template, that should equate to each value in your loop array.

Comment: I have it working with the save button working http://html5imageeditor.co.uk/kopush thank you